# Python multiple curve fitting models

Tags: python, r, curve-fitting

Is there a way to have an x,y pair dataset given to a function that will return a list of curve fit models and the coeff.  The program DataFit does this with about 200 different models, but we are looking for a pythonic way.  From exponential to inverse polynomial etc.

I have seen many posts of manually using scipy to type each model, but this is not feasible for the number of models we want to test.

The closest I found was pyeq2, but this is not returning the list of functions, and seems to be a rabbit hole to code for.

If R has this available, we could use that but python is really the goal

Below is an example of the data, we want to find the best way to describe this curve

[image]

Comment: I know that some people do this, but I believe it is bad practice. Non-linear models should be based on theoretical considerations. There is an unlimited number of non-linear functions, so why do you  believe that (i) one of your candidate functions represents the process that generated your data and (ii) that R² will identify the "correct"  function? I can understand doing something similar if you have a few potential candidate functions (e.g., sorption isothermes), but I wouldn't use R² as a decision criterion and I would never do this with 200 arbitrary functions.

Comment: @Roland the main reason is through testing multiple models, we can quickly see the resulting curves that statistically match the data best.  Then from the best few candidates either refine them or pick one.  For example, automatically testing 1 to 5th order polynomials and seeing if higher order is overshooting or fitting better.  So far the datafit software has worked for our needs, but it cost money and no flexibility in programming at all

Comment: @Roland the output we get is actually, StdError, Residual Sum, Residual Avg. RSS, R^2, Ra^2.  its just a fast way to find top ranked functions for us, as our main research background is not in this area

Comment: Well, I don't agree with your method of looking for "resulting curves that statistically match the data best". If that was your goal you should probably use a GAM. But I'm shutting up now. It's your data and you have to stand by your results.

Comment: The comment by @Roland is right on. This is just about the worst application of non-linear modelling that I have ever seen. It's appalling that people still do it. In addition, R.sq *is meaningless* for non-linear models. For linear models, R.sq is the fraction of variability explained by the model. For non-linear models *this is not the case*. Within a family (say, polynomials), models with more parameters will always produce larger R.sq, so this metric is useless to assess goodness of fit.

Comment: @Roland thank you both for your input, i took away the R^2 from the question and added an example of the data. i added the sample data as well, incase i get more unexpected, and great input

Comment: You should contact a statistician. It's impossible to give solid advice without much more information about the data. I see some "structures" that could indicate that you have time series/repeated measures. It's not obvious what your final goal is (inference, interpolation, prediction, ...), but maybe you could ask a question on stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we found that Eureqa software was able to achieve this.  https://www.nutonian.com/products/eureqa/

Answer (score 0):

You can try library splines in R. I have used this for higher order curve fitting to some univariate data. You can try to change and achieve similar thing with corresponding R^2 errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can either decide to do the following:

- Choose a model to fit a parameters. This model should be based on a single independent variable. This can be done by python's scipy.optimize curve_fit function. You can choose something like a hyberbola.
- Choose a model that is complex and likely represents an underlying mechanism of something at work. Like the system of ODE's from a disease SIR model. Fitting the parameters will be no easy task. This will be done by Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) methods. This is VERY difficult.
- Realise that you have data and can use machine learning via scikit learn to predict from your data. This is a method that doesn't require parameters.

Machine learning and neural networks don't fit something and can't really tell you about the underlying mechanism but can make predicitions just as a best fit model would...dare I say even better.